# Фон из многоугольников

Tags: javascript, svg

Необходимо сделать фон из многоугольников.

1. Фон случайным образом заполняется многоугольниками
2. Основа многоугольников это правильная фигура с равными рёбрами, но вершины должны случайным образом отходить от правильной фигуры. То есть к координатам каждой вершины прибавляем случайный вектор небольшого размера.
3. Цвета многоугольников заранее заданы палитрой, массив цветов.
4. При наведении мышкой на многоугольник запускается анимация смены цвета на заданный, увеличение размера, и возвращение в исходное состояние. Так же анимация случайного вращения вокруг центра во время трансформации цвета и размера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это Вопрос-Ответ в рамках обучающей инициативы нашего Ru.StackOverflow [SVG чата](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat).

Answer (score 9):

Первое что мы сделаем это научимся генерировать равнобедренные многогранники.

Итак наш код:

```
function MakeIdealMnogogrannik(rad, n) {
    var angle = 2 * Math.PI / n;
    var points = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        points.push({
            x: rad * Math.cos(angle * i),
            y: rad * Math.sin(angle * i)
        });
    }

    return points;
}
```

Далее напишем функцию которая сгенерирует равнобедренные многогранники и сохранит во внешнюю переменную

```
var radius = 22;
var minGranNumber = 3;
var maxGranNumber = 6;
var mnogograniksIdeal = new Array(maxGranNumber - minGranNumber + 1);

function MakeIdeals() {
    var number = maxGranNumber - minGranNumber + 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        mnogograniksIdeal[i] = MakeIdealMnogogrannik(radius, i + minGranNumber);
    }
}
```

Генерируем кривоугольники на основе правильных многогранников.

```
/* палитра цветов */
var colors = ["rgb(187, 61, 255)","rgb(255, 194, 61)","rgb(255, 255, 61)","rgb(61, 155, 255)","rgb(226, 61, 255)"];
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

/* передаём количество граней, расстояние на которое вершина может случайно отъехать в сторону, координаты кривоугольника */
function MakeRandomMnogogrannik(granNumber, distance, x, y) {
    var path = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "path");

    var points = new Array(mnogograniksIdeal[granNumber].length);

    /* случайно смещаем вершины равнобедренных многогранников что бы получить кривоугольник */
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        points[i] = {
            x: mnogograniksIdeal[granNumber][i].x + randomMax(distance) + x,
            y: mnogograniksIdeal[granNumber][i].y + randomMax(distance) + y
        }
    }

    var d = `M ${points[0].x} ${points[0].y}`;
    for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
        d += ` L ${points[i].x} ${points[i].y}`;
    }
    d += " Z";

    path.setAttribute("stroke", "black");

    var color = colors[randomMax(colors.length - 1)];
    path.setAttribute("fill", color);
    /* запоминаем цвет в кастомную переменную, что бы во время анимации можно было вернуться к исходному цвету */
    path.setAttribute("mycolor", color);

    var rot = randomMax(360);

    path.setAttribute("transform", `rotate(${rot} ${x} ${y})`);

    path.setAttribute("d", d);

    path.addEventListener("mouseover", MouseOver1);

    return path;
}
```

Функция заполнения области

```
var svg = document.getElementById("svg1");
var width;
var height;
var distance = 4;

function FillArea() {
    /* получаем ширину и высоту окна */
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(svg);

    width = parseInt(style.width);
    height = parseInt(style.height);

    /* вычисляем количество кривоугольников на основе плотности - density */
    var elementsNumber = density * width * height / (100 * 100);

    for (var i = 0; i < elementsNumber; i++) {
        /* ставим на случайную точку */
        var x = randomMax(width);
        var y = randomMax(height);
        /* чередуем количество граней */
        var path = MakeRandomMnogogrannik(i % mnogograniksIdeal.length, distance, x, y);
        svg.appendChild(path);
    }
}
```

Анимация при наведении мыши с использованием [SVG.js](http://svgjs.com/)

```
function MouseOver1() {
    /* получаем объект SVG.js */
    var rect1 = SVG.adopt(this);

    /* прекращаем и фиксируем ранее идущую анимацию если есть */
    rect1.finish();

    var rot = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 90;

    /* помещаем фигуру на самый верх полотна, что бы была видна анимация */
    svg.append(this);

    /* цвет для восстановления из кастомного аттрибута */
    var color = this.getAttribute("mycolor");

    /* увеличиваем размер и делаем заданный цвет */
    rect1.fill("rgb(255, 0, 0)");
    rect1.scale(1.4);

    /* запускаем анимацию */
    rect1.animate(1100, "-")
        .rotate(rot)
        .scale(1)
        .attr({ fill: color });
}
```

Результирующий код

```js
var svg = document.getElementById("svg1");
var minGranNumber = 3;
var maxGranNumber = 6;
var radius = 17;
var distance = 4;
var density = 60;


var mnogograniksIdeal = new Array(maxGranNumber - minGranNumber + 1);

var colors = ["rgb(187, 61, 255)", "rgb(255, 194, 61)", "rgb(255, 255, 61)", "rgb(61, 155, 255)", "rgb(226, 61, 255)"];

var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

function MakeIdeals() {
  var number = maxGranNumber - minGranNumber + 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    mnogograniksIdeal[i] = MakeIdealMnogogrannik(radius, i + minGranNumber);
  }
}

function MakeIdealMnogogrannik(rad, n) {
  var angle = 2 * Math.PI / n;
  var points = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    points.push({
      x: rad * Math.cos(angle * i),
      y: rad * Math.sin(angle * i)
    });
  }

  return points;
}

function MakeRandomMnogogrannik(granNumber, distance, x, y) {
  var path = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "path");

  var points = new Array(mnogograniksIdeal[granNumber].length);

  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    points[i] = {
      x: mnogograniksIdeal[granNumber][i].x + randomMax(distance) + x,
      y: mnogograniksIdeal[granNumber][i].y + randomMax(distance) + y
    }
  }

  var d = `M ${points[0].x} ${points[0].y}`;
  for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
    d += ` L ${points[i].x} ${points[i].y}`;
  }
  d += " Z";

  path.setAttribute("stroke", "black");

  var color = colors[randomMax(colors.length - 1)];
  path.setAttribute("fill", color);
  path.setAttribute("mycolor", color);

  var rot = randomMax(360);

  path.setAttribute("transform", `rotate(${rot} ${x} ${y})`);

  path.setAttribute("d", d);

  path.addEventListener("mouseover", MouseOver1);

  return path;
}

var width;
var height;

function FillArea() {

  var style = window.getComputedStyle(svg);

  width = parseInt(style.width);
  height = parseInt(style.height);

  var elementsNumber = density * width * height / (100 * 100);

  for (var i = 0; i < elementsNumber; i++) {
    var x = randomMax(width);
    var y = randomMax(height);
    var path = MakeRandomMnogogrannik(i % mnogograniksIdeal.length, distance, x, y);
    svg.appendChild(path);
  }
}

function MouseOver1() {
  var rect1 = SVG.adopt(this);

  rect1.finish();

  var rot = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 90;

  svg.append(this);

  var color = this.getAttribute("mycolor");

  rect1.fill("rgb(255, 0, 0)");
  rect1.scale(1.4);

  rect1.animate(1100, "-")
    .rotate(rot)
    .scale(1)
    .attr({
      fill: color
    });
}

function randomBool() {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function randomMinMax(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function randomMax(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1));
}


MakeIdeals();
FillArea();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.4/svg.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg1" style="width:100%; height:400px; background: rgb(187, 61, 255);" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
</svg>
```

[Ссылка на Codepen.](https://codepen.io/Okeanij/pen/pLpQBK)
[Дополнения версия с мозаичным текстом.](https://codepen.io/Okeanij/full/jzZzXG)

Comment: а с чем связано то, что при быстром движении курсора только некоторые фигуры лежащие на траектории движения активируются?

Comment: @yolosora видимо связано с обработкой движения мышкой браузером, если движение быстрое то смещение в каждом случае может быть больше чем размер фигуры, то есть идёт проскакивание. Пример сначала были координаты мышки 20,20 а при быстром движении следующие которые браузер или OS обработали это 42,42 , а то что между просто проскочило. При желании это можно исправить проводя линию между текущими координатами мышки и предыдущими.

Comment: @yolosora это можно поправить в алгоритме, вычислив соседние фигуры не от координат события `mousemove`, а соседние фигуры с линией проведённой между предыдущей координатой события `mousemove` и текущей